# cross compilation for OS X on linux

Tags: linux, macos, qt, ubuntu, compilation

How can I compile the Qt application for OS X on Linux?
Actually, I could accomplish that for Windows, and I can help you if you need help, by using MXE but for MAC I couldn't find any useful answer neither on the Qt website nor inside the forums.
I would appreciate if someone has any idea or experience.
P.S: I know that is better to compile the application on OSX itself to be sure about the result and I have MAC notebook to do that, however, I just curious to know more about the cross-compilation feature of Qt for MAC on Linux.
P.S: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: There's no way to cross compile. You need to get macOS running somewhere.

Comment: @peppe You are right because I also asked the Qt support team but they didn't have any answer and now, I'm working with Electron that seems better and newer cross-platform framework.